# React: Link to a div on another html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a link

```
<a href="about.html#div2">Click me</a>
```

When I click the link I am brought to about.html at the top of the document.

If I am already visiting about.html and and I type about.html#div2 in the search bar of my browser(chrome), then my browser goes down to the specific div(div2).

I tried going to the component that loads the other page and inside ComponentDidMount, adding something like

```
var sectionName = window.location.hash.slice(1);

//then show the section
$('#' + sectionName ).show();
```

But for some reason the div is still null. How is it null if the component mounted?

Using a Link Component also doesn't work, as I need to put it in a router, which I've done using

```
<HashRouter>

        <Link style={linkButton} to={about.html#div2}>Learn more</Link>
</HashRouter
```

But this really seems to do nothing.

How can I get my browser to visit the div on the other page from the link on another page.

---

**Update**

This is what my about component looks like essentially

```
class About extends React.component {
    constructor(){
        var p = props;
        var Style = {
            display:'flex',
            flexDirection:'column'
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        var sectionName = window.location.hash.slice(1);

        //then show the section
        $('#' + sectionName ).show();
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div style={Style}>
                <Service id='div1' serv={Service1}/>
                <Service id='div2' serv={Service2}/>
                <Service id='div3' serv={Service3}/>
                <Service id='div4' serv={Service4}/>
                <Service id='div5' serv={Service5}/> 
            </div>

    )
    }
}

var Service = (props) => {
    var serv = props.serv;
    return (
        <div id={props.id}>
            ....
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery with React?

Comment: @JohnRuddell Cause I'm a noob. I take it I shouldn't?

Comment: Haha, jQuery and React are both trying to accomplish the same thing. You shouldn't be using them together. Rather, use the react eco system to show a section. You can use a state variable and conditionally show something. Hard to know what / where this issue is without more context though

Comment: You could also in the `componentDidMount` of the component that renders your `#div2` do something like `document.getElementById('#div2').scrollIntoView()` if you're trying to scroll an element into the viewport

Comment: document.getElementById('#div2') is always null, I can't do anything with it, even in componentDidMount

Comment: Which componentDidMount? There is a component that mounts `#div2` somewhere no?

Comment: The one for the div2 component. This component basically just returns a div with the id div2

Comment: Do you mind sharing some code or maybe setup a codesandbox or something? the react component that renders `div2`, in didMount it definitely would be mounted assuming you have assigned the id to the div. Its really hard to help without something to work off of.

Comment: I uploaded it, I might have the did mount part on the wrong component

Comment: Where's the html element that gets the ID? aka `<PicsWText` is not a html element its another component.

Comment: your issue is the hash id you are specifying doesn't match the id. `'Div1' !== 'div1'`

Comment: That was actually just an issue when uploading it on here, I changed the names of things

Comment: Oh, sorry did you try removing the `#` in the `document.getElementById`? aka `document.getElementById('div2')` [**Like this example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-6018t)

Comment: In that example i just made a change to use hash, you have to put the hash in the url for the preview view. and trigger a change in the code to see it work

Comment: So document.getElementById retrieves the div now, it's saying `show` is not a function, do you know what function could be used?

Comment: Show is jQuery. Drop that shiz haha. Just call `scrollIntoView()`. like this `document.getElementById('div2').scrollIntoView()`

Comment: Thank-you, it works

Comment: Yay!!! Glad that did it :) I'll write up a solution for you so we can close the question out then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using both jQuery and React together. They are trying to accomplish the same thing (DOM management / manipulation)

Instead just use a DOM accessor to grab the id and scroll in componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount () {
    const myId = window.location.hash.slice(1)
    const elem = document.getElementById(myId).
    if (elem) {
      elem.scrollIntoView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly certain what you are trying to accomplish, but I can give you some tips related to what you wrote:

First, the React equivalent to `document.getElementById()` is `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.nodeName)` and you must remember to
`import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

In order to use this method, you must create a ref on your div 
`ref={ ref => this.nodeName = ref }`

Also another tip, I am not familiar with how you are organizing your components in the DOM, but I personally do not use html links in my JSX. You can simply add `onClick={this.myClickFunction}` to any div. This gives more freedom in handling clicks in JS.

Comment: I think that I couldn't use ReactDom.findDOMNode because using `ref` involved turning all my stateless functional component into classes, which I really didn't want to do

Comment: Oh that is true. I was going to also recommend to try .focus() instead of .show() in your componentDidMount but I saw you found another solution!

Comment: A hash and scrolling to that hash is a fairly standard web practice, using refs is a more react way but not good for this use case since you'd have to keep a separate mapping from hash to ref.